# retrieving a historic balance for a later date

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a dataset with the following data: (simplified)

```
accnr:     date:       balance:
zz123      1-1-2020     100
zz123      2-1-2020     110
zz123      3-1-2020     120
zz123      4-1-2020     130    (note: last date stored for zz123)

zz234      1-8-2020     50
zz234      2-8-2020     100
zz234      3-8-2020     75
zz234      4-8-2020     85
zz234      5-8-2020     95    (note: todays date)
```

I want to request the balance of the last known date:
This date is the max of the distinct dates. so this is `5-8-2020`.

if i request the balance of `zz234` for last date `5-8-2020`, i get as a result: balance for `95` `5-8-2020`.

i want to retrieve the balance of `zz123` as well for `5-8-2020`. But the table does not have an entry for `5-8-2020` for account `zz123`. So no value is returned. Is there a way to get this?

In the system i am only able to use T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.accnr = t.accnr);
```

Another method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(date) over (partition by accnr) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
 where date = max_date;
```

A fun method uses `top (1) with ties` and `row_number()`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by accnr order by date desc);
```

Comment: Thanks. These queries give me the last value for the accnr. Is it also possible to have for the most recent value of zz123 also date  5-8-2020? I was thinking about a loop with IN to run through all dates from 1-1-2020 to today.?    select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t.date IN (  SELECT DISTINCT date  FROM t    )   )) from t t2 where t2.accnr = t.accnr)

Comment: thanks for closing the question by the way. I was probably not to clear in the last alinea where it is really about. -->i want to retrieve the balance of zz123 as well for 5-8-2020. But the table does not have an entry for 5-8-2020 for account zz123. So no value is returned. Is there a way to get this? <--